# fonts supported by android devices

Tags: coronasdk

I am developing an android application using corona sdk,but i am not able to support all the custom fonts in my application.Many of the fonts which are supported in simulator are also not getting supported in the device.Very few fonts are getting supported in the device like ayuthaya.What is the reason for this? Can anybody give me any solution regarding this and also the list of fonts which is supported in the device.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to download the fonts from the internet if you don't have them on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Download the font file (ttf or otf format) from the internet and include it on your project when building for Android. The device should be able to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you should install the font on your computer. You can do that by right clicking your font and open with Windows Font Viewer. Then install the font and keep in mind the font name displayed in Windows Font Viewer because you are going to use that name as parameter(not filename of the font) in the code. And finally drag the font file into your project folder where your main source file is and also into project in IDE. After that, you should be able to view the font.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the file name, it should be the same as you call it in your project.
Sometimes you would have to rename .ttf file.

To make it visible in simulator copy downloaded font file to windows/fonts folder.